# create multiple workbooks in certain folder location

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Lets say I want to create 5 workbooks in certain location. I was trying to use this code but it doesn't work. (run-time error, automation error), what is wrong with it?

```
Sub blabal()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Set wbk = Workbook.Add

Do Until i = 5
    wbk.SaveAs "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\abc\" & i
    wbk.Close
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: add the line `Set wbk = Workbook.Add` inside the `Do` loop, as first line, before `wbk.SaveAs "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\abc\" & i`

Comment: should be Workbook**s** `Set wbk = Workbooks.Add` and make sure the path `"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\abc\"` exists

Comment: path was ok. as @Slai said the biggest problem was with the "s" :)Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

`Set wbk = Workbooks.Add`

You need to specify `Workbooks` instead of `Workbook`.

`Workbooks` is a collection object. You're adding a `Workbook` to the collection of `Workbooks`.

You also need to change the order of your code, so you're either not closing the workbook each time, or so that you are closing the workbook, but you're then adding a new workbook (which doesn't really make much sense, but I'll show an example anyway).

```
Set wbk = Workbooks.Add

Do Until i = 5
    wbk.SaveAs "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\abc\" & i
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

**Or**

```
Do Until i = 5
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Add
    wbk.SaveAs "F:\" & i
    wbk.Close
    i = i + 1
Loop
```